# How to return variable from jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you help me please...
How to return variable from jquery function

```
var height = $(window).height();

$(window).resize(function(){
    var height = $(window).height();
    return height;
});

setInterval(function() {
    $('div').append( 'Index: ' +  height );
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to return. Try this:

```
var height = $(window).height(); // define "height" here

$(window).resize(function(){
    height = $(window).height(); // update "height" variable, 
                                 // don't user "var" here.
                                 // because using "var" will redefine
                                 // "height" again and no longer contain the
                                 // updated value on window resize 
                                 // out of this resize function scope
});

setInterval(function() {
    $('div').append( 'Index: ' +  height );
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `var` you're creating a new variable, not overwriting the original. You'll want this instead:

```
var height = $(window).height();

$(window).resize(function() {
    height = $(window).height();
});

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the answer to your question depends on how you want to return it. Console? Alert? A div or other element? See below for a list.

- console.log(height)
- alert(height)
- $("#elementID").html(height); // or whatever selector and method work for your case

I suppose you could also convert that $(window).resize block into a function, then call that function.  That should work, too.